# Wix - Embedded Script with customizable parameters

Tags: velo

I have a simple script that I want to embed in the Wix website on the footer of every page. The script has some parameters which are dynamic. My initial thought was to set up an [Embedded Script](https://dev.wix.com/docs/build-apps/developer-tools/extensions/embedded-scripts) but it requires a POST API to supply the dynamic parameters.

I want to provide users with a Custom Apps Form where they can supply or tweak the parameters as in the picture and generate the script tag automatically.

Is it possible with Wix Extension? What type of Wix Extension supports this flow?

[image: Wix Embedded Script]